# Redoing file paste on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, copy-paste

I sometimes download files to my desktop, test/view them and then move them to where they belong, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. On occasion, I forget to close a program that's using such a file (e.g. a PDF reader). In those cases, some files move successfully, but others fail.

After I closed the offending programs, how can I redo/continue to paste the remaining files with one keyboard shortcut? I'm using Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 3rd party softwares to achieve that. For example, [**TeraCopy**](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php) and [**Piky Basket**](http://www.conceptworld.com/piky/piky_features.asp) are two good copy/paste management programs.